# Why does a string method not work in home controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I placed the following code in my Home Controller. But when I try to navigate to localhost:xxx/chkDoc I get a 404 error. But when I place the same code in other controllers the I have success and appropriate string is returned. All my settings are default project settings that VS2012 generates. Any ideas why this is happening/working only in other controllers?

```
public string chkDoc()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return "authorized";
    }
    else
    {
        return "gotologin";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it works to `localhost/Controller/chkDoc`

Comment: Yes sorry I read the question backwards the first time.

Comment: @FloodGravemind - shouldn't that be `localhost/Home/chkDoc`?

Comment: @EricPetroelje Thanks but I realized my mistake and Igor beat you to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url (route) must include controller name and action method name - in that order. You may skip the action name (the default will be substituted), or you may skip both controller and action names (defaults will be used for both), but you cannot skip the controller name.